# Change default qemu VNC port range

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I have changed the default VNC port range inside the qemu configuration file like the following:

```
remote_display_port_min = 59900
remote_display_port_max = 59920
```

So based on the above, when I have a `'-1'` option to the xml definition file of my VM, then, the VNC port should be between the above range.

My problem is that it looks like I need to restart the whole server in order the changes to take effect.

Is there any way to reload any relevant service(s) and whithout losing my running VMs to have the configuration altered on the fly? Or at least I don't have to lose my server for several minutes (due to reboot process).

I am on a CentOS7 (3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64) server with qemu version 2.0.0 and libvirt 1.2.17.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why don't you just restart libvirtd?

Comment: @MichaelHampton because if I do so, I will lose for a few minutes my running VMs. Also, if I remember correctly, when I tried your suggestion, although I had a successful `libvirtd` service restart, the qemu VNC default ports were still the same.

Comment: Restarting libvirtd does not restart running VMs (unless your system is _really_ broken). But you would have to shut down and restart them to change their VNC port, as that is allocated when the VM starts.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so you suggest that if I restart `libvirtd` and then shutdown and start again each VM, then a new VNC port should be applied based on the qemu.conf file?